# How to properly connect bluetooth to Rpi3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth

I have tried many tutorials on how to attach bluetooth to the pi, but none seem to work, i dont know if the ones I am reading are outdated or depreciated but I have had no luck, I am trying to connect my bluetooth speaker/mic combo to the RPi3 Model B. I have succesfully been able to connect it and get sound from youtube but that is it. I am trying to TTS working on a website called runmyrobot.com, which allows users to type in chat, and then my robot speak the chat. I also have had no luck getting the microphone to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How have you ruled out the possibility that this is not a problem with your bot?

Comment: @SteveRobillard nope others are using it just cant get ahold of them

Comment: In the GUI have you selected your speaker (right click) in the sound menu (blue speaker on the right side of the menu bar - neear the clock)

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all USB Bluetooth adapters compatible with Raspberry Pi. Make sure your USB adapter is compatible. I believes this [article](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Bluetooth_adapters) may help you to find out a compatible Bluetooth adapter.
To install the software needed to support Bluetooth, enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez-utils blueman bluez 
$ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
```

These commands should work for all Bluetooth adapters supported by the Raspberry
Pi.

Now you want to plug your Bluetooth adapter. You can check the Bluetooth adapter is connected or not using this command after hot plugging the Bluetooth adapter:

```
$ lsusb
```

Its output looks like this if Bluetooth adapter is connected:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:2198 Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Device
```

If not found don't bother about it. Just reboot your Pi. You will now find a new entry on the Raspbian Start menu under the Preferences section called Bluetooth Manager. Open this utility and click Search to look for nearby
Bluetooth devices. Make sure that there are some Bluetooth devices set
to be discoverable. It is my first answer. I don't know is Stack exchange expecting these kind of answers...

Comment: It is the first good answer I have got. I think Stack Exchange expects you to berate and belittle the person first THEN answer the question.

Comment: @Chris Thank you. I believes now you successfully attached Bluetooth to the Pi. Is it really helpful for you? Since I am not a native English speaker and I faced some troubles to understand what you are saying. That is why I am asking this.